# Сортировка списка из списка и элемента

Tags: python

Есть массив вот такого вида

```
k=[[[0.5, 2.5], 6], [[2.14, 2.14], 8], [[2.14, 2.14], 4]]
```

необходимо получить следующий результат

```
k=[[[2.14, 2.14], 4], [[0.5, 2.5], 6], [[2.14, 2.14], 8]]
```

Подскажите как это можно сделать?
Вот эти методы не работают

```
sorted(k, key=itemgetter(1))
sorted(adaptive, key=lambda i: i[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(sorted(k, key=lambda x: x[1]))
# [[[2.14, 2.14], 4], [[0.5, 2.5], 6], [[2.14, 2.14], 8]]
```

Comment: Понял в чем моя ошибка, не сохранял в переменную полученный результат.. спасибо за ответ